# Issue with displaying my website's updated favicon in Android and Apple mobile google search engine results

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-search, google-search-platform

I am using WordPress as a platform for my website. I used plug in real favicon generator and gained instantaneous results for my favicon on every platform except "android and ios google search engine." It is however showing me the old favicon and not updating the recent one. I changed the favicon 4 days ago.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png?v=vMQMeew0Ox">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=vMQMeew0Ox">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png?v=vMQMeew0Ox">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest?v=vMQMeew0Ox">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=vMQMeew0Ox" color="#5bbad5">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=vMQMeew0Ox">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

I tried using realfavicongenerator.net and created my favicon. On top, I included the code in my root directory, but I am still not getting updated results for google search engine. I have even deleted the old favicon from the root directory.

I expect the updated favicon for the website in google search engine results.

Comment: Did you try to upload favicon through Apperance->Customizer?

Comment: Yes..i started solving the issue with the same